# D3 how to find the height of the last point in a line graph

Tags: d3.js, svg, linegraph

I am very new to d3, somehow have been able to draw a line graph with animation as following:

```
 var lineData = _.first(data.data, 30); // some array of numbers

            var  xRange = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([0, 30]),
              yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([_.min(lineData), _.max(lineData)]);

            var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
              .x(function(d) {
                return xRange(lineData.indexOf(d));
              })
              .y(function(d) {
                return yRange(d);
              })
              .interpolate('basis');

            var path = vis.append('path')
              .attr('d', lineFunc(lineData))
              .attr('stroke', color)
              .attr('stroke-width', 3)
              .attr('fill', 'none');

            var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

            path
              .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
              .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
              .transition()
              .duration(5000)
              .delay(index * 1000)
              .ease("linear")
              .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

Now I want to add at the end of each line some text(denoting name of each line).
I can do that using the following code

```
vis.append("text")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + (WIDTH - 15) + "," + 200 + ")")
          .attr("text-anchor", "start")
          .style("fill", "steelblue")
          .text("Close");
```

Now my problem is that the text node to be appended has to be at height where the line graph ends( and replace the currently hardcoded y=200).  I am not able to achieve that , please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this example : http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8603837

```
svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width+3) + "," + y(data[0].close) + ")")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .text("Close");
```

So in your case, from your fiddle :

I have got the bounding box of the path to work out the X translation (get the end point of the path) :

```
 var translateWidth = document.getElementsByClassName("pathLine")[0].getBBox().width;
```

And for the Y translation, I have passed the last value of the array to the yRange like so :

```
yRange(lineData[lineData.length - 1])
```

So now your text function is as follows :

```
vis.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (translateWidth + 50) + "," + yRange(lineData[lineData.length - 1]) + ")"
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .style("fill", "black")
    .text("abc")
```

Notice I changed the append from `path` to `vis` as you can't append text to SVG elements like you were trying to do.

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/dqch1s13/4/

Working code if needed here :

```js
var vis = d3.select('#visualisation'),
  WIDTH = 1000,
  HEIGHT = 400,
  MARGINS = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 50
  };

var drawLine = function(data, color, index) {
  var lineData = data;
  var xRange = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([0, 30]),
    yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([_.min(lineData), _.max(lineData)]);

  var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return xRange(lineData.indexOf(d));
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return yRange(d);
    })
    .interpolate('basis');
  console.log(lineData[lineData.length - 1])
  var path = vis.append('path').attr('class', 'pathLine')
    .attr('d', lineFunc(lineData))
    .attr('stroke', function(d) {
      return color
    })
    .attr('stroke-width', 3)
    .attr('fill', 'none');

  var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

  path
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
    .transition()
    .duration(5000)
    .delay(index * 1000)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
  console.log(path)
  var translateWidth = document.getElementsByClassName("pathLine")[0].getBBox().width;

  vis.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (translateWidth + 50) + "," + yRange(lineData[lineData.length - 1]) + ")"
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .style("fill", "black")
    .text("abc")
};

drawLine([1, 20, 3, 4, 15, 6, 7, 18, 9, 0, 12, 23, 24, 12, 100], 'red', 2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<svg id="visualisation" width="1200" height="400" style="position: absolute;left: 50%;transform: translateX(-50%);"></svg>
```

Comment: if you get together a JSFiddle, I can implement it

Comment: Hey thanks for the help ,  I saw this example but  y(lastDataElement)   I dont know what this is .  Anyway I put together a rough fiddle here  https://jsfiddle.net/dqch1s13/   .  I basically need to append text "abc" at the end of the line after the animation completes.

Comment: Hey Thanks, I figured out what that y means. Able to do it now.

Comment: @SahilSharma as the answer has solved your problem, you could select it as the correct answer by hitting the tick ? Just so that other users can see it

Comment: I definitely would  because it was really helpful,but unfortunately it doesnt allow me to do that  as I have low reputation on stackoverflow. I guess I need to start answering to increase it

Comment: Or you can upvote my question to give me some repo. :)

Comment: its 15.  I am sure about that. Because I tried it before you even mentioned it. Even for my other questions

Comment: @SahilSharma somone with 3 points of experience just accepted my other answer for a different question.... Youre probably doing it wrong